# Show a list of an user's followers/following and check whether I follow them with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, system, social-networking

I'm working on a social networking site which has a follow system. I've got the whole follow and unfollow part down as well as display a list of an user's followers/following.

However, displaying a follow/unfollow button within that list for each individual user is something I am struggling with for that user.

My question is: how can I check whether I (logged in user) am follow someone within that list or not, to show the appropriate follow/unfollow button?

```
'follow' TABLE STRUCTURE:

id | id_initiator | id_target | follow_date
-------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 2         | 2014-08-15 23:47:09
```

To show the list of an user's followers I'm using an INNER JOIN query to combine the 'users' table and 'follow' table :

```
SELECT users.id, follow.id_initiator, users.fullname, users.seoname, users.avatar, users.total_followers
FROM users
INNER JOIN follow
ON users.id=follow.id_initiator
WHERE follow.id_target=$profile_user_id /* (the id of the page owner) */
ORDER BY follow.followdate DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Now, how do I go about checking if I (`$_SESSION["user_id"]`) am following someone from this list or not? Do I do this in the query? Create an array and loop through that?

Comment: Yes, you are nearly there. I would change that `INNER` to a `LEFT` so you get all users, regardless of whether there is a `follow` record. You'll need to adjust your `WHERE` clause to allow this. Then if you have a `id_initiator` value, you know there is a follow relationship (so you should offer Unfollow) and if the column is null, there is no relationship (so you should offer Follow). You may wish to paginate it as well, otherwise it will get unwieldy for large numbers of users.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, if you can use the code formatting tool, it renders ASCII tables nicely, and negates the need for break tags in code. I've fixed up the post.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question and your reply, halfer. About your answer, I'm not sure whether I completely understand it. For example, when visiting someone's profile and going to his/her following page, I want to so who he/she is following. So I would have to use the WHERE clause, right?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna create an sqlfiddle for this. I'm new here, so I don't know how this all works just yet. I very much appreciate you guys help!

Comment: I created this sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6855d7/3)